# Understanding datetime formats in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, date-format

I've dealt with MS SQL Server datetime types for a long time but never thought why the following is happening:

1. I query a table that contains a smalldatetime column. This smalldatetime is always returned in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`
2. Now I write a different query on which I want to apply a smalldatetime filter in the WHERE clause, something like `WHERE TimeStamp >= 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'`
3. SQL Server retrieves an error and tells me that was not possible to convert that nvarchar to a valid smalldatetime

It appears that it only works if I change the specified format and I write it using the european format, like `WHERE TimeStamp >= 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'`.
Why is SQL Server showing me the dates in a format that is not covertable or valid when applied back to itself?
I don't have any problem in changing the date format when writing queries, but I want to play with these dates at an application level (Java-JDBC app) and I don't want to be applying date format changes all the time...
Could anyone explain me why this is happening and if there is any way to solve it at a DB level?
Thanks!!

Edit: Please see the screenshot of the error in Management Studio below.
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only truly safe formats for DATETIME/SMALLDATETIME in SQL Server are:

```
yyyyMMdd
yyyyMMdd hh:nn:ss[.mmm]   -- or up to [.mmmmmmm] for datetime2 etc.
yyyy-MM-ddThh:nn:ss[.mmm] -- or up to [.mmmmmmm] for datetime2 etc.
----------^ yes, that T is important!
```

Anything else is subject to incorrect interpretation by SQL Server, Windows, the provider, the application code, end users, etc. For example, the following always breaks:*

```
SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-11-13');
```

Result:

> Le paramètre de langue est passé à Français.
>
> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>
> La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites.

Just changing the language (which any of your user sessions can do) forced SQL Server to interpret that as `YYYY-DD-MM` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`. Similar things can happen with setting like `DATEFORMAT`. But these settings are literally ignored when using the above two formats.

Always, always, always use one of the above two formats. If you are passing a variable as a string, stop doing that. If you can't, check to make sure it passes `ISDATE()` first. If you are letting people type any date string into a form field, stop doing that, too. Use a date-picker or calendar control and dictate the format of the string before you pass it to SQL Server. Well, depending on the language, just keep it as a datetime value and don't convert it to a string at all.

- [I can't reproduce your problem at all, btw](http://rextester.com/WKF68795)...

Please read this post:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Mis-handling date/range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

*<sub>There is an exception: `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd');` will not break. But I err on the side of consistency rather than using a format only in the one place where I know it doesn't break, and having to use a safer format everywhere else.</sub>*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64583/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-bertrand-understanding-datetime-formats-in-sql-ser).

Answer (score 5):

According to SQL Server Books Online [Write International Transact-SQL Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307.aspx) you could wrap your date strings like so:

```
{ ts 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff] '}
```

Example:

```
{ ts '1998-09-24 10:02:20' }
```

This might be easier to accomplish for you because instead of inserting a `T` in the middle, you are just concatenating strings at the beginning and the end.

One caveat: you have no control over the precise type when using this syntax; the result is always *datetime*. To achieve a *smalldatetime* result (as in the question), you would need to use a convert (or cast). In which case, you might as well use just *convert* (with the correct style parameter) in the first place.